# WePay checkout/create prefill_info json

Tags: asp.net, .net, json

I am having an issue sending the prefill_info information to auto populate the checkout fields. The documentation calls for a json inside the json request.

The json I'm sending is {"name":"value","zip":"value","email":"value"}
But I'm receiving "invalid_request: expecting JSON for parameter prefill_info".

Comment: if someone with a 1500+ reputation can create a "tag" called "wepay" and tag this, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I actually passed the raw object "values" (no json formatting or serialization).

```
    Dim values As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    values.Add("name", d.first_name & " " & d.last_name)
    values.Add("zip", d.zip)
    values.Add("email", d.email)
```

Now, works like a charm.